# How to pass variable value to external bat file

Tags: batch-file

I need help in passing a variable value of a batch file to another batch file.

I am using this statement:

```
call vartest.bat 

if %username%==NA (
echo First login detected.

set /p usernameIN= Username:
@echo set username=%usernameIN% > vartest.bat
)
```

The problem is that, the value of "usernameIN" does not pass-on to the external batch file. I tried it using normal text instead of the variable and it works.

Is there any way to make this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Thanks Man! :D
Can you post it as an answer? So I can set your response as an aswer to my query.

Comment: @echo set username=!usernameIN! > vartest.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need delayed expansion if you want to use a variable, that you changed in the same block (a block is a series of commands within brackets (and ))

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call vartest.bat 

if %username%==NA (
  echo First login detected.
  set /p usernameIN= Username:
  @echo set "username=!usernameIN!" > vartest.bat
)
```

Also you should use `set "var=value"` to avoid unintended spaces in the variable.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) for a short demonstration of delayed expansion.